# Sumif with named range using INDIRECT()

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs, excel-indirect

I have a named range *TYPE_NAME* which is a list of types of projects. Correspondingly, a named range *TYPE_VALUE* contains "Yes"/"No" for each type.

Then, for each entry in *TYPE_NAME*, there is a corresponding man hour value stored in a named range "HC_" where  is the entry in *TYPE_NAME*. All the *HC_xxxx are scattered in various locations* within my workbook.

Question: Is there a worksheet formula that can calculated the total sum of man hour for each TYPE with `VALUE = "Yes"`?

I tried the following array formula but it is not working.

```
{=SUMIF(TYPE_VALUE, "Yes", INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("HC_",TYPE_NAME)))}
```

It always use the 1st entry in TYPE_NAME and sum the continuous column of HC_<1st entry> according to the `TYPE_VALUE="Yes"` criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a helper column. Assuming the Range Type_Name is in column A, with the first name in cell A2, you can use the formula

=indirect("HC_"&A2)

Then you can use a sumif against the Type_Value and the helper column.

Comment: looks like it is the only option. Thanks.